# How can I show this function sequence is Cauchy in $C([-1,1])$ with $||f|| = \max|f(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

The function sequence is

\begin{equation}
    f_n(x)=x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}
\end{equation}

I know that, in order to prove it, I need to show that given $\varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||f_m -f_n|| < \varepsilon, \ \forall m, n \geq N$.

I've shown that

\begin{equation}
    ||f_m -f_n|| = \max_{x \in[-1,1]} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}-x^{1+\frac{1}{2m-1}}| \leq \max_{x \in [0,1]} |x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}-x^{\frac{1}{2m-1}}|
\end{equation}

and, from what it looks like in Desmos, the $\max$ of that function decreases as $N$ increases, but I don't know how to prove it. I've tried to work out the derivative of $g_{n,m}(x) = |x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}-x^{\frac{1}{2m-1}}|$ and find the zero of that and see how it decreases with $N$, but there must be an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to prove that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to some function in $f\in C([-1,1])$. And it does. Just take $f(x)=|x|$ and use the fact that$$f_n(x)=x^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}=|x|^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}=|x|^{1+\frac1{2n-1}}.$$So, since the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The problem is that I need to prove that $C^1([-1,1])$ with the previous stated norm is **not** complete. So I know that the limit exists but it just doesn't in the space that I'm considering.

Comment: @BraisRomero Then consider the functions in $C([-1,1])$ first. The fact that the sequence is convergent in $C([-1,1])$ means it is Cauchy, which makes it Cauchy in $C^1([-1,1])$ as well (or any other subspace which contains the sequence).

Comment: @TheoBendit yeah, okay, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $C([-1,1])$ **is** complete with respect to that norm.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: It is a mistake to drop the factor of $x$. Note that $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| <2\epsilon $ if $|x| <\epsilon$. Observe also that $f_n(-x)=f_n(x)$ so we are left with the case $x \geq \epsilon$. Now  $|x^{1/(2n-1)}-x^{1/(2m-1)}|\leq |x^{1/(2n-1)}-1|+|1-x^{1/(2m-1)}|$ and the inequality $e^{-t} \geq 1 -t$ show that $|x^{1/(2n-1)}-1| \leq \frac 1  {2n-1} \epsilon^{1/{2n-1}} \to 0 $ (and similarly for the second term).

Comment: I'm not seeing why $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| <2\epsilon$ if $|x| <\epsilon$ tbh

Comment: $|x^{1/{2n-1}}-x^{1/{2m-1}}|\leq 1+1=2$.  You have to keep the $x$ factor. @BraisRomero

Comment: Okay, yeah, I see it now, but where does the inequality $e^{-t} \geq 1 -t$ come from?

Comment: That is a basic inequality in Calculus:  The derivative of $1-t-e^{-t}$ is $e^{-t}-1 \leq 0$ for $t \geq 0$ so $1-t-e^{-t}$  is a decreasing which function which has the value $0$ when $t=0$. Hence it must be $\leq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.  @BraisRomero

Comment: Proving uniform convergence to $x$ also requires the inequality I wrote and it is not simpler than  my proof.  @BraisRomero